# Using "getline" With Arrays

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>      // for the strlen() function

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    const int Size = 15;
    static char name1[Size];                    //empty array
    static char name2[Size] = "Jacob";      //initialized array

    cout << "Howdy! I'm " << name2;
    cout << "! What's your name?" << endl;
    cin >> name1;
    cout << "Well, " << name1 << ", your name has ";
    cout << strlen(name1) << " letters and is stored" << endl;
    cout << "in an array of " << sizeof(name1) << " bytes" << endl;
    cout << "Your intitial is " << name1[0] << "." << endl;
    name2[3] =  '\0';   

    cout << "Here are the first 3 characters of my name: ";
    cout << name2 << endl;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

## The Issue

the only issue in this code is that if you type your name with a space, it will skip the last name after the space. The getline() method can solve this, but I can't seem to get it all right. There may even be a better method to solving this. To sum it short, I want to be able to enter both a first and last name (one full name) when prompted from the start.

## The program

The program simply prompts and use to input their name, and then outputs the users name, along with size in bytes and the first three characters of the user's name.

Comment: It would be better to use `std::string`.

Comment: It may be; however, I am trying to learn how to do this with arrays.

Comment: If this is homework and you're *required* to use arrays, go ahead. Otherwise, you're better off ignoring arrays and just using `std::string`.

Comment: It's a homework assignment, but I do agree.

Comment: `the only issue in this code is that if you type your name with a space, you will crash the program.` are you sure? I don't think that is correct. Also, what do you plan on doing if the name is longer than 15 characters?

Comment: Technically, it does not "crash" the program, but it does skip ahead and close it right after you type it.

Comment: @Jake2k13, That's because you only read two characters at the end and everything after the space (including it) is still there.

Comment: The "right way" to do this with an array is to dynamically allocate an array and parse the name into it a character at a time(see [`istream::peek`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) and [`istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)), resizing as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use getline method like this:

```
cout << "! What's your name?" << endl;
cin.getline(name1, sizeof(name1));
cout << "Well, " << name1 << ", your name has ";
```

To count non-space characters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>      // for the strlen() function
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    const int Size = 15; 
    static char name1[Size];                    //empty array
    static char name2[Size] = "Jacob";      //initialized array
    cout << "Howdy! I'm " << name2;
    cout << "! What's your name?" << endl;
    cin.getline(name1, sizeof(name1));
    cout << "Well, " << name1 << ", your name has ";
    int sz_nospace = count_if(name1, name1 + strlen(name1), 
            [](char c){return c!=' ';});
    cout << sz_nospace << " letters and is stored" << endl;
    cout << "in an array of " << sizeof(name1) << " bytes" << endl;
    cout << "Your intitial is " << name1[0] << "." << endl;
    name2[3] =  '\0';   

    cout << "Here are the first 3 characters of my name: ";
    cout << name2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, This is an acceptable answer. But is there a way you can omit spaces between the words as getting "counted"? My program counts the space as a character in the name. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I think this answer would be better if the `count_if` was stored in it's own statement and not in a printing statement.